# Trying to retrieve QcomboBox selection from with QtableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have a function that inserts multiple QcomboBoxes in the first row of QtableWidget and then updates an excel file starting in row 2. This is at the end of my function:

```
    for i in range(df.shape[1]):
        combo = comboCompanies(self)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, i, combo)
```

What I would like to do is know when one of the indexes is changed on a combobox but they currently have the same name so I need to figure out how to uniquely identity them. I found the following but it isnt in Python

```
        QComboBox* myComboBox = new QComboBox(); // making a new dropdown box
        myComboBox->setObjectName(QString::number(i)); // pass column number as object name
        connect(myComboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)), 
        SLOT(onComboChanged(QString)));
        ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0,i,myComboBox); // put box into table
```

How do I code in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify Your Combobox eihter by setting it's objectname or just by passing it's column as a parameter to the callback.

`currentIndexChanged` signal only gives You new changed index, but not the Combobox itself. That's why we have to use inline lambda function.

Here is the code with both options used:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QComboBox


def index_changed_id_by_column(column: int, selected_index: int) -> None:
    """combobox in column changed selected_index"""
    print(f"Combobox in column: {column}, changed to index:{selected_index}")


def index_changed_id_by_combobox(combobox: QComboBox, selected_index: int) -> None:
    """combobox changed selected_index"""
    print(f"Combobox: {combobox.objectName()}, changed to index:{selected_index}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create some Table
    table = QTableWidget()
    table.setRowCount(2)
    table.setColumnCount(4)

    # Solution 1, using column index to identify Combobox
    for i in range(table.columnCount()):
        combobox = QComboBox()
        combobox.addItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])
        '''
        This connects currentIndexChanged signal with lambda function (selected_index, column), 
        calling index_changed_id_by_column slot
        '''
        combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            lambda selected_index, column=i: index_changed_id_by_column(column, selected_index))
        table.setCellWidget(0, i, combobox)

    # Solution 2, using objectName to identify Combobox
    for i in range(table.columnCount()):
        combobox = QComboBox()
        combobox.setObjectName(f"combobox_row1_coll{i}")
        combobox.addItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"])
        '''
        This connects currentIndexChanged signal with lambda function (selected_index, combobox), 
        calling index_changed_id_by_combobox slot
        '''
        combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            lambda selected_index, combobox=combobox: index_changed_id_by_combobox(combobox, selected_index))
        table.setCellWidget(1, i, combobox)

    table.show()

    app.exec()
```

In first row we have Comboboxes calling `index_changed_id_by_column` callback.
In second row Comboboxes calling `index_changed_id_by_combobox` callback.

Pick the one that You need for Your project.

Comment: Martin-Thanks so much for taking the time...Works great!

Comment: How would I return the Qcombobox selection on a change? I tried adding: txt=combo.currenntText() to the lambda function and it always gives me the first item in the combobox and not the item I selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Please ask new question with Your problem in SO.  Since I don't know Your current code, I can just guess the issue.  What should work, is calling `combobox.currentText()` from `index_changed_id_by_combobox`. It won't work in lambda function for `combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect` if that's what You are doing. You must first get combobox object based on it's column and get currentText() from `index_changed_id_by_column` callback. But in general get currentText from `changed` callback only, You should not need any lambda for that.

Comment: @Domarm...It worked thank you again!